# IOS 8 APIs and IOS 6 deployment target

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7, ios6, ios7.1

With drastic change in iOS from 7 onwards most of the Apps prefer **iOS6** looks , same with my App which uses 3rd party LIB. 
I have copied all platform from old iOS to latest iOS and it works great till when recently 3rd party library I am using in my app are using Text-font **(UIFontTextStyleCaption1)** supported from ios7 onward in there lib. Now when I use recent release in my app I am getting linking error as my deployment target is **iOS6.1**. My app works great if I change my deployment target to latest **iOS8.1.1**.

Is there any way I can link library or make it visible as I have both both platform within latest Xcode.

Is it possible... as I can not change my deployment target and need 3rd part library as well...

Comment: Drop support for iOS 6. Only support iOS 7 and 8. Move forward.

Comment: I agree with @rmadddy either drop support or you would have to upgrade your Library

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you think most of the users preffer iOS 6 as official [Apple statistics](https://developer.apple.com/support/appstore/) clearly states that only 4% of all users are still on iOS 6 **and below**.

[image]

With thus said I strongly advice you to drop iOS 6 support as it has numerous problems, except of missing APIs.

To directly answer you question - it's really hard to support 3rd party libraries. They are meant to be used as-is instead of modifiyng. If you had the source code you can try to refactor newer API calls to use old(and probably deprecated) methods. However most of the libraries(and this is the preffered way for library) are just binaries without source code. This binary is probably build with newer deployment target and in this way your only shot is using older version of the library or(even worse) making some reverse engineering and building this library on your own.

UPDATE

I've just checked one of our apps database(over 5000 unique users) where we do support iOS 6, and the percent is 4.5% which matches apple site.

Comment: hmm thank you, i will not be able to update as my client some how did not like ios7 + looks of our App(was really in mess), its little big app and in production used by many users ...and need to fix some issues so can not think of really updating as such.... so directly speaking there is no work around.... :(